# Your Windows License Will Expire Soon

Tags: windows, activation, license-key

How can I temporarily remove the showing of "Your Windows License Will Expire Soon" on my laptop?
I am currently doing lots of things right now and I don't want to address this problem for now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it doesn't have anything to do with programming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because nothing to do with programming

Comment: Ridiculous, how can you say it has nothing to do with programming?  It's interrupting his programming; that's good enough for me.  Sure wish someone would answer it.

Answer (score 1):

try in cmd `slmgr /rearm` it will reset the counter to 30 days

> This command can only be used several times, so you can’t indefinitely
>   extend the trial. The number of time it can be used depends on the
>   “rearm count,” which you can view using the slmgr.vbs /dlv command. It
>   seems different on different versions of Windows–it was three times on
>   Windows 7, and it seems to be five times on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Please note:

> This no longer seems to work on Windows 10, which is very lenient if
>   you don’t provide it a product key anyway. This option still works on
>   older versions of Windows and may continue to work on other editions
>   of Windows, such as Windows Server, in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I'm currently waiting if it appears again just to be sure. I will accept this answer later.

Comment: I´m glad I could help you :-) Have a nice day

Comment: See this Video to solve your issue.

https://youtu.be/lzbl-LGAq9g